# Is there a way to disallow robots crawling through IIS Management Console for entire site

Tags: iis, seo, robots.txt

Can I do the same as robots.txt through IIS settings? 
Telling

```
User-agent: * Disallow: /
```

in host header or through web.config?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a robots.txt file?

Comment: Because of deployment issues.

Comment: "Because of deployment issues" - using an approach which would prevent access (robots.txt is just a polite request) will not be possible by your criteria. The obvious way to prevent access would be to resitrict to a whitelist of IP addresses. But that's at least as difficult to deploy as a robots.txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not a specified way. Either have the `robots.txt` or the HTML-Meta-Tag as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element#The_robots_attribute

There are only these two options available.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single robots.txt file stored somewhere on your web server, and redirect all requests to any site hosted on your IIS server for robots.txt to that file.  That would be a change per site in IIS, but you may be able to do it programmatically with PowerShell.